# How to add gradient effect on canvas circle's minor arc?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

[image]

I am trying to add the gradient effect of the small arc in my canvas. Using

```
context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 400. 400);
secondGradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');
secondGradient.addColorStop(0.2, 'black');
secondGradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'black');
secondGradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');
```

But unable to get the expected results, also would be great if someone can explain how createLinearGradient works with circle.

Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/x4tcboj3/1/.

Comment: Remove the shadow and you'll see the white gradient `this.context.shadowBlur = circle.blur; this.context.shadowColor = 'hsla('+circle.hue+', 80%, 60%, 1)';`

Comment: I just updated [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/x4tcboj3/2/), now the white line is gone. I can get the white line, but the idea is to have the edge effect of the arc's end. If I had to gusse, I think I am doing something wrong with the `context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 400. 400);` part. :(

Comment: I got the white line updating 
`secondGradient.addColorStop(0, 'black');
secondGradient.addColorStop(0.2, 'white');
secondGradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'white');
secondGradient.addColorStop(1, 'black');`

 http://jsfiddle.net/x4tcboj3/3/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally. I was kind of right about being wrong about `createLinearGradient`, so I went [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) to read more about `createLinearGradient` turned out I had to set two points where I want the gradient effect to start.

[image]

(Silly me, read the documentation) I was trying some random point to get the results. I added a `onmousemove` event to mind out the exact point, and set to 
`const secondGradient = this.context.createLinearGradient(20, 90, 75, 230);` works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/x4tcboj3/4/